# .htaccess file disappears from live serever

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using Racspace server, whose directory structure is as

```
ROOT > web > Content
```

All of the files are placed in `content` folder. But when I place .htaccess file it automatically disappears. and rules doesn't work. Whereas it is working fine on local server
The rules that are defined in .htaccess file are

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([0-9]*)?$ dashboard.php?user_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
```

Comment: Contact Racspace support.

Comment: have you tried uploading first as `htaccess.txt` then renaming to `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes I have tried.. As I rename it disappears

Comment: How is it uploaded? FTP, SSH, Web upload, DAV? Try one of the other options then.

Comment: I am uploading via FTP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a FTP program like FileZilla, than click "Server" and than click "Force show hidden files" and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that its actually there, you just need to know to see it. In linux any filename starting with a `.` is considered hidden and will not display by default.

If you are access the file via ssl, you can see hidden files with `ls -a`. If you are using another client, you may need to configure it to show hidden files.

Comment: I am using FTP client.. Then how I can see hidden files using FTP

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman That is going to depend on your client. Likely there is a setting that controls that.